# Device to install on a bottle to only spill drops

Tags: sauce

When heating up cold food in microwave it oftens comes out pretty dry, and I like juicy food. So I add 1 or 2 teaspoons of olive oil on the food before heating it. I'd be easier though if I had some kind of small device

Comment: add a smidge of water to your left-over noodles before cooking them in the microwave - the steam works wonders.

Comment: I'm sure I've seen some device similar to the one described by Jay that only allows 1-2 drops of the liquid to come out. Ask in a specialized store.

Comment: Consider a "Soy Sauce" bottle.

Comment: Can you please clarify. Your question title mentions "drops" but your body says you use 1-2 tsp of oil. Which do you want?

Comment: 1-2 tsp is the quantity, I just want to spread it uniformily on the food which is hard using a spoon or a normal bottle.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I did a cheap kitchen hack by reusing an empty Sriracha bottle after cleaning and drying it up for my oil drops. Here is how the bottle looks:

[image]

And it is perfect for dropping oil. The nozzle also lets me increase or decrease the diameter of the oil drop.

If you don't happen to like this sauce, try it with some Asian food. You'll love it mostly!!!

Answer (score 16):

What you are looking for is pretty common and can be bought in most markets in the kitchen section. Or ordered online by search "olive oil bottles".  They look like this:

[image]

Comment: You can get them at liquor supply stores, they are used in bars for easy pouring of liquids inside bottles

Comment: The inconvenient to this "device" is that it doesn't spill drops as is.

Comment: I have one of these and it does not allow for droplets;  it slows the pour down based on the magnitude of the wrist movement behind it.

Comment: @JWiley Thought the title says "Drops" the question body says 1-2 tsp... which implies that the OP isn't actually looking for something that allows drops. The question is unclear.

Answer (score 12):

Plastic squeeze bottles come in a variety of sizes, offer a bit more control and are very inexpensive. Just make sure to get one that is food grade.

[image]

Comment: You're not supposed to put oil in plastic unless it's HDPE plastic. So says BulletProof, who sells high grade MCT oils. Omega Nutrition also uses HDPE plastic for their oils.

Answer (score 3):

Another option for oils is a mister.

[image: Olive Oil Mister]]

That allows you to spray a bit of oil across all of the food - or spray it on the pan for cooking.  There are a lot of different kinds of misters (as well as just 'sprayers' more like what you'd use to spray water on a plant or similar; the "misters" mostly work by pumping to pressurize).

Answer (score 1):

Mio bottles would be quite handy. I've used them for cooking oil when I need a small amount for camping trips.

[relevant reddit discussion on the safety of reusing the bottles](https://www.reddit.com/r/lifehacks/comments/1ex7w6/recycled_mio_bottle/)

Answer (score 0):

An oil/vinegar cruet is designed for exactly this purpose:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Plastic bottles are cheap. I bought 3 mustard dispensing bottles from the pound store (with the narrow head). I have used them extensively for vinaigrettes and controlled drops of sauces.